# Unity quicklist for home is messed up

Tags: 12.04, unity, nautilus, quicklists

I can't change Home Folder quicklist options. Everything I do, I continue to have:

Documents folder link
Pictures folder link

```
Music folder link
Downloads folder link
Ubuntu One folder link
Ubuntu One folder link (as you can see, it's a duplicate)
Video folder link
New Window action

Separator
Home folder link (bold)
Separator

Unlock from launcher
```

This is my  `~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`, that is exactly the same as  `/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Home Folder
Comment=Open your personal folder
Exec=nautilus %U
Icon=user-home
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.0.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus
Actions=Window;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=nautilus
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home folder quicklist options are defined by your bookmarks in Nautilus. Add/remove them from the Bookmark menu in Nautilus and the changes will show up in the quicklist.